# How to modify variable data in PDF templates with prawn? (if possible)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

I have PDF templates which each contain the same variable data. *Can I use prawn to:*

1. Select the template
2. Update the variable data
3. Generate PDF from DB data

[image] 
[image]

***Ultimately I would like to do something like this:***

```
Prawn::Document.generate("template_#{file}.pdf") do |pdf| 
  pdf.date db.created_on
  pdf.name db.name
  pdf.message db.message
  pdf.id db.id
  pdf.price db.price
 # . . .
```

(If not possible with prawn) Please give your suggestions to quickly tackle this problem. Perhaps tips or recommend a different gem?

> From prawn docs I get the concept of using a grid and text boxes as a
>   way to generate the PDF file *(trying to avoid doing all of that work)*
>   because I know it's possible to work with variables in PDF's with
>   other applications, so I'm hoping to be able to do the same with prawn
>   or other PDF generation gem.

Comment: Are those fields actual form fields? Or are they given by means of coordinates?

Comment: @mkl I'm not sure I follow. The pictures are PDF templates. I am trying to avoid using grid/coordinates to populate the data on the PDF from my DB. I would like to just specify a var say: `name` and have prawn find `name` on the PDF template and populate it's value from the DB without the use of coordinates. `name` is the same on many PDF templates but the coordinates would be different for each. Make sense? Thanks for your help. FYI the final product has to print on a 4x6 card which I why I am using PDF to force the output -- I am open to other formats. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: I assume the actual name replacing the place holder `name` may be longer than the placeholder `name`. How shall the program know how much space it may use? Especially `message` seems to be multiline; how should the program know where to break lines?

Comment: The red outline around `name` is the text-box on the PDF. I was hoping I could look up the coords of the text-box by var (`name` in this case) For `message` after I get coords I can split the `message` with `\n` where appropriate. Basically instead of specifying coords statically I want to dynamically access their values. Does that make sense?

Comment: The appropriate way to do that in the context of PDF in general would be by means of form fields (which may eventually be flattened). Unfortunately I do not know whether you can do that using prawn, let alone how you can do that. But maybe that is something to search for.

Comment: Hi, Were you able to get the coordinates?